# Различные названия программы(файла) и процесса.

Tags: argv, c++, linux

Здравствуйте.

Каким образом можно реализовать следующую задачку:
Имеется программа someprogram, при запуске ./someprogram программа запускается и в ps/top процесс называется так же - someprogram. Как сделать так чтобы при названии программы someprogram процесс назывался anotherprogram?

Читал что необходимо играться с argv[0]

Comment: И где Вы такое читали?

Comment: http://www.uofr.net/~greg/processname.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот это в линуксе

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS \n \l

avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ uname -a
Linux avp-ubu1 3.2.0-38-generic #61-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 19 12:18:21 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

работает (хотя в `man proc` я не нашел `/proc/self/comm`, но он "вычисляется")

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ cat progname.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define MY_NEW_NAME "new_prog_name"

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  printf ("I want to change name from [%s] to [%s]\n", 
      av[0], MY_NEW_NAME);
  fflush(stdout);
  system("ps");
  puts ("Hit ENTER for continue...");
  getchar();

  int fd = open("/proc/self/comm",O_WRONLY);
  if (fd > 0) {
    write (fd,MY_NEW_NAME,strlen(MY_NEW_NAME));
    close (fd);
  } else {
    perror("open");
  }

  puts ("see result:");
  system("ps");

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc progname.c
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
I want to change name from [./a.out] to [new_prog_name]
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1919 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 2958 pts/0    00:00:00 a.out
 2959 pts/0    00:00:00 sh
 2960 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
Hit ENTER for continue...

see result:
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1919 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 2958 pts/0    00:00:00 new_prog_name
 2961 pts/0    00:00:00 sh
 2962 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
End
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Хочу еще добавить, что содержимое `/proc/self/cmdline` (первый элемент там -  это argv[0]) не меняется, также как и символьный линк `/proc/self/exe`, который указывает на исполняемый файл.

Так что, надежно обмануть "серьезные" программы таким способом (изменить имя для top,ps,...) не получится.

Comment: Для занудного g++ надо еще добавить `#include <unistd.h>`

Comment: спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант - создать ссылку на исполняемый файл (жесткую или символическую) с каким-то именем и запускать через нее. Тогда процесс будет иметь ее имя.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Как вариант - да, но не в моем случае.